# how to check in between two numbers, if one number is much greater than the other in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

While finding roots of a quadratic equation, subtractive cancellation is an issue when b^2 is much greater than 4ac. So, I need to first check whether the given equation has this issue or not. Then if there's an issue, I need to find an alternative way which is to calculate r=-(b+sign(b)*sqrt(delta)) and then we get the roots 2c/r and r/2a. I am struck at checking b^2 is much greater than 4ac.

Comment: What about `if b^2 > 1000 * 4*a*c then %other method%` ?

Comment: Why is it an issue? What do you mean 'much greater'?

Comment: @ptay89 much greater means >>

Comment: @Macduff I am not quite sure. why only 1000?

Comment: @user3410357 We are talking programming here and not just mathematics, so we need numbers. That's why you need a number on how to define "much greater".

Answer (score 1):

Solutions are:

1. Use VPA (symbolic toolbox), which is probably the best solution to deal with precision errors on arbitrary calculations.
2. Use the build in function `roots`, which deals with this issue very well.
3. The precision of a double value is known. Based on a required precision, you can define a boundary.